# map urls to plugins

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, urls, front-end

I'm just getting started in plugin development and written some admin functionality by referring to the codex.

However, I now want to add some functionality to the front end, but using some URLS such as:

- `/items`
- `/items/item-slug`
- `/items/search/term`

So, what I would like to do is somehow intercept these urls in my plugin so they map to specific functions in the plugin. These would be display pages with other logic to fetch data, process posted data etc.

All I need is pointing in the right direction for the functions I need to be using.

Thank you.

Comment: no research at all? :(

Comment: no helpful link at all?  :(

Comment: http://google.com

Comment: @MarkKaplun "google it" is explicitly considered bad manners in SE network. You could probably actually google and post a resulting link to codex in time it took you to leave these comments. :) Please be nice.

Comment: I kniow, @Rarst but he did ask for a useful link in his comment. I know I should have just not answered it

Comment: I understand the frustration at what sometimes appears to be very little effort on the part of the poster. However, I do state I have been referring to the Codex. That I did "no research", is an assumption on your part. I think you'll agree that the Codex is pretty comprehensive and there is nothing wrong with turning to a resource like SE for guidance. Moreover, that is what I specifically asked for: pointing in the right direction. I didn't wanted a canned solution that I can copy and paste, just some guidance so I  can figure this out myself and learn in the process.

Comment: @timstermatic, I think rarst covers all the options, how much that answer help you? It is not the lack of research by itself, it is just that the resulting question is broad and there are not many limiting factors to it. You could have limited it by being more detailed in what you need or knowing already what are the options.

Comment: Ok, I'm ending this conversation here. I'm doing my research based on what @Rarst posted. I'll accept it as soon as I have found all I need (which I believe I have). What you are saying above is different from your initial comment of "no research at all". I have put as much detail as is required for what I want to do in the question. If you don't think the question is good enough, edit it.

Answer (score 1):

The general implementation of such "pretty" permalinks in WordPress is realm of WP Rewrite. However it is pretty wide topic and low level code is a bit of abomination.

I would say these are three most common techniques for it, complexity ascending:

1. Use WordPress native data structures (such as Custom Post Types and/or Taxonomies) and benefit from "magical" permalinks support provided for them.
2. Add a limited extensions to existing permalinks, using *endpoints*. This works quite well for simpler use cases.
3. Go all the way with rewrite and define completely custom rules. This is most powerful, as well as most messy.

[Rewrite API documentation in Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API) would be a start.